# How to fix "Could not find the correct Provider<Product> above this ProductItem Widget "?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I am very much new to flutter. This is my first time using providers. I have been through every solution out there but nothing seems to help.

In a shopping app I am developing, I tried to use the provider package to pass data to my widget dynamically.

I am sharing the code and the screenshot of the very big error message. Hope somebody could help

**Gridview builder**

```
final productData = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context);
final products = productData.items;
return GridView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  itemCount: products.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: products[index], child: ProductItem()),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 0.75,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10),
);
```

**Individual product item in the grid**

```
final product = Provider.of<Product>(context);
return Container(
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamed(ProductDetails.routeName, arguments: product.id);
    },
    child: Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 6,
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          //product image
          Image(image: AssetImage(product.imageUrl)),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
            //item name and fav button
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                  product.name,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline1
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                )),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      product.isFav
                          ? Icons.favorite
                          : Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      product.toggleFav();
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // price and buy button
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                  "\$ " + product.price.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.copyWith(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 15),
                )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Text(
                      "Buy",
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Prompt', fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkgdv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the provider in you main material widget. Atm you are using it but you haven't told flutter that you will use it.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider